# What does $a$ is a root of $f(x)$ $\text{modulo}\; \mathfrak p$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have a ring $A$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ and a polynomial $f(X)\in A[X]$ and also $a\in A$.

I have read in several books phrases like "$a$ is a root of $f(x)$ $\text{modulo}\; \mathfrak p$" or "$f(a)\equiv 0$ $\text{modulo}\; \mathfrak p$" and also "$a$ is a root of $f(X)\; \text{modulo}\; \pi$" where $\pi$ is a generator of $\mathfrak p$.

Could someone please explain what these mean? I know the definitions of a prime ideal and its generator but I'm confused about what "modulo" means in these cases. This is probably a trivial question for most people but it's causing me problems as I'm just a novice in math.

Many thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's another way to say $f(a) \in \mathfrak{p}$. In fact, in this case you have $\overline{f(a)} = \bar{0}$ inside the factor ring $A/\mathfrak{p}$.

EDIT: You will find this notation in the literature, so take advantage of it. Consider the canonical projection $$A \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak{p}$$
then for any element $x \in A$, the symbol $\overline{x}$ denotes the element of $A/\mathfrak{p}$ corresponding to $x$. Other notation to denote it are
$$[x]_{\mathfrak{p}}$$
$$x \mod{\mathfrak{p}}$$
$$x+ \mathfrak{p}$$
They are all the same thing, i.e. the equivalence class $\{ x+p :p \in \mathfrak{p}\} \in A/\mathfrak{p}$.